# Tesseract training with multipage tiff

Tags: tesseract

How does the box file need to look like if I use a multipage tiff to train Tesseract?

More precisely: how do the Y-coordinates of a box file correspond to Y-coordinates within pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last, 6th column in the box file represents zero-based page number.

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Make-Box-Files

Update:

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract

> Each font should be put in a single multi-page tiff and the box file
>   can be modified to specify the page number for each character after
>   the coordinates. Thus an arbitrarily large amount of training data may
>   be created for any given font, allowing training for large
>   character-set languages.

Even if you can have as large training text as you want, it could potentially result in unnecessarily large image and hence slow down training.

Comment: Thank you, I must have missed that. Do you happen to know what maximum number of pages Tesseract supports?